# Exempt form from clickable behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I have a some textboxes enclosed in an expanding top bar, that is, a strip on the top of the web page that, when clicked, toggles the following expand/close behavior.

```
var toggle = true;
$("#expandable").click(function() {
    if (toggle == true){
        $(this).stop().animate({"height":"300px"},500);
        toggle = false;
    } else {
        $(this).stop().animate({"height":"50px"},500);
        toggle = true;
    }
});
```

Now, my only problem is that, when I click on the text boxes, the expanding div believes its being clicked (Fair enough it is). But I don't want the top bar to close when I click on the forms.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prevent event from bubbling if it happened on input element:

```
$("#expandable :input").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This way click event will not reach click handler on `#expandable` element.

Special selector [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) matches inputs, textareas, selectboxes.

Comment: Ohh this is awesome! And it works :D. Fantastic dfsq.

Comment: One more thing, say I also had buttons in this expandable div, is there a simple way to stop the click handler for the expandable tabs when the buttons are clicked?

Comment: You mean in addition to `:input` you also want to prevent collapse on buttons click? If so then you can do this: `$("#expandable").find(':input, button').click(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var toggle = true;
$("#expandable").off('click');
$("#expandable").on('click',function() {
    if (toggle == true){
        $(this).stop().animate({"height":"300px"},500);
        toggle = false;
    } else {
        $(this).stop().animate({"height":"50px"},500);
        toggle = true;
    }
});
```

You could also write it this way to prevent bubbling.